# pass a hidden input array to jquery load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

im trying to send a hidden input type that contains an array to my jquery load(function) however im having trouble in making it work

table_planner.php

```
foreach($category->result() as $c){
    <input type="hidden" name="tname[]" id="tname[]" value="<?php echo $c->name;?>" />
}

<div id="planner">
<!--load content goes here-->
</div>
```

script.js

```
var tname = $("#tname").val();
console.log(tname);
$('#planner').load(base+"site/table_planner/"+tname)
```

controller

```
public function table_planner($tname="")
{
    if($tname){
    $data['category'] = $this->site_model->get_category();
    }
    else{
    $data['category'] = $tname;
    }

    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view("site/ajax/table_planner");   
}
```

what i want to happen is

1. from table_planner.php - the value of the hidden input with id tname[] will be send to my script.js
2. from script.js the variable tname will be sent to table_planner in my controller

the problem starts with my script.js not being able to get the value of my hidden input value because console.log(tname) says it is undefined but if i echo out its value in table_planner.php it contains a value

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `tname[]` for?

The id in your html is `tname[]`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tname[]" id="tname[]" ...
```

but in your js is `#tname`:

```
var tname = $("#tname").val();
console.log(tname);
```

Change the `id` in you html to `tname`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tname[]" id="tname" value="<?php echo $c->name;?>" />
```

---

**update for passing the whole array**

```
$tname = '';
foreach($category->result() as $c){
   $tname .= '&tname[]=' . $c;
}
// $tname will be like &tname[]=cake&tname[]=food...
```

set it to html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tname" id="tname" value="<?php echo $tname;?>" />
```

in js, call the url `base+"site/table_planner/"`

```
var tname = $("#tname").val();
console.log(tname);
$('#planner').load(base+"site/table_planner/?"+tname)
```

in the url `base+"site/table_planner/"`, there must be a php file to process the request:

```
var_export($_GET);
```

you will see the `tname` is an array.

Comment: tried this and now console.log is now showing something however it only shows the first value of the array

Comment: OK, You want to send the content of array `tname` to this url: `base+"site/table_planner/"+tname`, what is the value you expect?

Comment: the tname is going to look something like this $tname[0] = cake;$tname[1] = food;$tname[3] = utensils;$tname[4] = drinks;